Problem in booting to newly installed ubuntu 20.04 from current ubuntu 24.04's grub after purging and reinstalling grub
I have installed windows 11 and ubuntu 24.04 on two separate drives. I would like to install ubuntu 20.04 on a third drive. The installation is successful.
I can boot into ubuntu 20.04 and 24.04 from the grub in ubuntu 20.04 without problems, but I prefer to boot through the original 24.04's grub.
I went inside the ubuntu 24.04, and purge and reinstall the grub (because update-grub didn't work). However, I still cannot boot into 20.04 from 24.04's grub.
The error is
error: no such device: 6b829898-dc76-4da2-b8e8-ab1010c3ae50
error: unknown filesystem
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Here is the boot repair summary.
boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20240830_1114]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme1n1.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme1n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme1n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 3 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   The OS currently in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on nvme1n1p2
OS#2 (linux):   Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on sda2
OS#3 (windows):   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: AD106 [GeForce RTX 4060 Ti 16GB] simpledrmdrmfb from NVIDIA Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic root=UUID=4a5c3ee7-c73c-418b-96c5-075e973c1e3f ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/nvme1n1p2 ext4  915G  336G  533G  39% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 1661(16.61) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0000,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,02e2f416-54c9-4ba5-bbe3-36ffd588f004,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000031000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,1cdebf65-2051-4b15-be87-9d431ada893a,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,02e2f416-54c9-4ba5-bbe3-36ffd588f004,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi) File(.)
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,482716ef-cd65-4189-ae3c-5f90b8a8f871,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)0000424f
Boot0005* UEFI:CD/DVD Drive BBS(129,,0x0)
Boot0006* UEFI:Removable Device BBS(130,,0x0)
Boot0007* UEFI:Network Device   BBS(131,,0x0)

07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
66f69798ad23240e43b7ba0044a914c4   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
64e4182ead3316166f817dcc6131cd7a   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
522f1fff3eaefbaeb449d98436d24041   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
d4646b0af24b169d62bc44cff8967793   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
522f1fff3eaefbaeb449d98436d24041   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
cfc91f581a0eb379f573d7bbced9061c   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
378f8a2aae778974836aea7a73116b74   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
0dddc55d593fc13c3ab3cb750e1a188a   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi
66f69798ad23240e43b7ba0044a914c4   sda1/Boot/bootx64.efi (is grub)
66f69798ad23240e43b7ba0044a914c4   sda1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme1n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme1n1p2   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme1n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme1n1p2   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme1n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme1n1p2   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme1n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme1n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme1n1
sda2    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: 1BD28D85-5D88-4D97-8869-62BD13773CA3
             Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048    206847    204800  100M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    206848    239615     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    239616 975390719 975151104  465G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 975390720 976771071   1380352  674M Windows recovery environment
Disk nvme1n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 3659DC28-AB6E-46C4-BE68-00D3C21FFD4C
           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme1n1p1    2048    2203647    2201600     1G EFI System
nvme1n1p2 2203648 1953521663 1951318016 930.5G Linux filesystem
Disk sda: 447.13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk identifier: 3938A7D5-3B25-46BC-B933-C0CB9C29A18E
       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
sda2  1050624 937701375 936650752 446.6G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:480GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA KINGSTON SA400S3:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:480GB:480GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:500GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp, no_automount;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres, no_automount;
3:123MB:499GB:499GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:499GB:500GB:707MB:ntfs::hidden, diag, no_automount;
nvme1n1:1000GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:CT1000T500SSD5:;
1:1049kB:1128MB:1127MB:fat32::boot, esp;
2:1128MB:1000GB:999GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                  
├─sda1      vfat     B43C-D0FB                            482716ef-cd65-4189-ae3c-5f90b8a8f871       EFI System Partition
└─sda2      ext4     6b829898-dc76-4da2-b8e8-ab1010c3ae50 6f154b16-6571-47bd-9e31-e4fad37ec6cf       
nvme0n1                                                                                              
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     087C-581E                            02e2f416-54c9-4ba5-bbe3-36ffd588f004       EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               b58a2c54-1270-4103-a81f-151ef1d7d249       Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     16A07CCDA07CB539                     998cbe34-b6c2-4ed4-ab36-f5bcc4b77fe5       Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     32DCA969DCA927D5                     53ebcf2e-c8f3-4466-b4ec-85319bfc38c1       
nvme1n1                                                                                              
├─nvme1n1p1 vfat     3187-546D                            1cdebf65-2051-4b15-be87-9d431ada893a       
└─nvme1n1p2 ext4     4a5c3ee7-c73c-418b-96c5-075e973c1e3f 802b9e1d-215b-45aa-b314-e9c51551ae44       

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                     Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1                       60.9M  37% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3                        179G  62% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4                       81.8M  88% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme1n1p2                      532.8G  37% /
/dev/sda1                           505.9M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2                           407.2G   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
efivarfs                             37.2K  78% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1                      vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3                      fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4                      fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme1n1p2                      ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda1                           vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda2                           ext4            rw,relatime

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 6b829898-dc76-4da2-b8e8-ab1010c3ae50 root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme1n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 4a5c3ee7-c73c-418b-96c5-075e973c1e3f root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme1n1p2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   4a5c3ee7-c73c-418b-96c5-075e973c1e3f
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme1n1p1)   osprober-efi-087C-581E
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (20.04) (on sda2)   6b829898-dc76-4da2-b8e8-ab1010c3ae50
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme1n1p2/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4a5c3ee7-c73c-418b-96c5-075e973c1e3f / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
UUID=3187-546D  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

==================== nvme1n1p2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme1n1p2: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 100.274219513 = 107.668623360  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  98.595951080 = 105.866596352  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
  64.916259766 = 69.703303168   boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic                  1
  98.595951080 = 105.866596352  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic                  1
  64.916259766 = 69.703303168   boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 186.808589935 = 200.584196096  boot/initrd.img                                7
   3.947311401 = 4.238393344    boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-31-generic               1
 834.940120697 = 896.510128128  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic               2
 186.808589935 = 200.584196096  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic               7
 834.940120697 = 896.510128128  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

=================== nvme1n1p2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4 06:12 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4 06:12 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4 06:12 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4 06:12 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4 06:12 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4 06:12 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr  4 06:12 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr  4 06:12 41_custom

====================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   6b829898-dc76-4da2-b8e8-ab1010c3ae50
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-087C-581E
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (24.04) (on nvme1n1p2)   4a5c3ee7-c73c-418b-96c5-075e973c1e3f
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=6b829898-dc76-4da2-b8e8-ab1010c3ae50 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=087C-581E  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 276.635753632 = 297.035378688  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  37.480491638 = 40.244371456   boot/vmlinuz                                   1
  37.480491638 = 40.244371456   boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-119-generic                1
  44.954097748 = 48.269094912   boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-67-generic                 2
  44.954097748 = 48.269094912   boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 304.438472748 = 326.888321024  boot/initrd.img                                7
 304.438472748 = 326.888321024  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-119-generic             7
  46.882286072 = 50.339471360   boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-67-generic              2
  46.882286072 = 50.339471360   boot/initrd.img.old                            2

===================== sda2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18224 Dec  2  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 Dec  2  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13101 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Dec  2  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Dec  2  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Jul  2  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec  2  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Dec  2  2022 41_custom


I will share my solution to my own question. It looks like that ubuntu20.04 doesn't install the grub boot loader in its drive properly. I am not able to boot into 20.04 drive. Fixed the problem by reinstalling the grub in 20.04's drive via the boot repair disk tool in live session. There, I am also able to update the priority boot system. Now I can boot into 24.04 as a priority system from whatever disk either 20.04 or 24.04.
